# Window.open() could not open new webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

Window.open() could not open new webpage?

Is it because of my JavaScript, or there is there a problem anywhere else in my code?

```js
function getage() {
  var age = document.getElementById("customerage").value;

  if (age > 21) {
    window.open = "beer.com";
  } else if (age > 0) {
    window.open = "http://lol.disney.com/games/tsum-tsum-tower";
  } else
    alert("Please input correct age!");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>I drink alcohol.com</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="Sumei" content="Alcohol Web">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcom to "I drink alcohol.com"</h1>
  <h3>Here is couple of questions for you:</h3>
  <p>How old are you?</p>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="customerage" id="customerage" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="getage()" value="OK">
  </form>

  <script>
  /* getage function*/
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using `window.open` incorrectly, [read documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) on how it is used

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to go to pages based on iteration result 
well try this piece of code, also you are not using window.open() correctly that should be used like **window.open(URL, "_blank", option);** if you want it to open in new tab

else go for code below

```
if(age>21)
{
window.location="beer.com";
}


else if(age>0)
              {window.location="http://lol.disney.com/games/tsum-tsum-tower";}
              else 
              alert("Please input correct age!");
          }
```

well also what i think you should add something in your elseif like

```
else if(age>0 && age <21)
```

Answer (score 0):

just use window.open

```
var option= "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
var link = URL + location.href;
var win = window.open(link, "_blank", option);
```

Answer (score 0):

use **window.open()** to open in new tab, and use **window.location.href** to open link in same tab

```
<html>
            <head>
              <title>I drink alcohol.com</title>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta name="Sumei" content="Alcohol Web">
            </head>`
            <body>
             <h1>Welcom to "I drink alcohol.com"</h1>
             <h3>Here is couple of questions for you:</h3>
             <p>How old are you?</p>
             <form method="post">
             <input type="number" name="customerage" id="customerage"/>
             <input type="submit" onclick="getage()" value="OK">
             </form>

             <script>
              function getage() {
                  var age = document.getElementById("customerage").value;

                  if(age>21)
                  {window.open("beer.com");}

                  else if(age>0)
                  {window.open("https://www.google.com");}
                  else 
                  alert("Please input correct age!");
              }
             </script>

            </body>
        </html>
```